# java.lang.ClassCastException when deserializing Scala object

Tags: scala, serialization, sbt, deserialization, ammonite

So I have an object like this

```
case class QueryResult(events: List[Event])
```

that I need to serialize deserialize. For serialization I have this implicit class

```
  implicit class Serializer(obj: Object) {
    def serialize: Array[Byte] = {
      val stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
      val objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(stream)
      objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj)
      objectOutputStream.close
      stream.toByteArray
    }
  }
```

It's used like

```
val byteArray = QueryResult(events).serialize
```

Then for desrialization I have this trait that can be extended by the companion class.

```
trait Deserializer[A] {
  private type resultType = A
  def deserialize(bytes: Array[Byte]): A = {
    val objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(
      new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)
    )
    val value = objectInputStream.readObject.asInstanceOf[resultType]
    objectInputStream.close
    value
  }
}
```

You would use it like so

```
object QueryResult extends Deserializer[QueryResult]
```

Then you should be able to reconstruct an instance of `QueryResult` from a byte array like so

```
val QueryResult: QueryResult = QueryResult.deserialize(byteArray)
```

The issue is this sometimes causes an error like the one below

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.generic.DefaultSerializationProxy to field co.app.QueryResult.events of type scala.collection.immutable.List in instance of co.app.QueryResult
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2205)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2168)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1422)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2450)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2357)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2166)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1668)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:482)
  at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:440)
  at co.app.Deserializer.deserialize(Types.scala:51)
  at co.app.Deserializer.deserialize$(Types.scala:47)
  at co.app.LocalStorage$QueryResults$.get(LocalStorage.scala:241)
  ... 36 elided
```

Now when I say sometimes I mean the deserialization works when I assemble the code into a jar and run it using the `java` cli, but it breaks when I try to execute that code via `sbt test`, `sbt console`, or `ammonite`. Any idea why it breaks under these circumstances and possible suggestions to fix?

Comment: How do you serialize the object that you try to deserialize? Does it work if you serialize then deserialize in the same execution (i.e. something like `deserialize(serialize(myObject))`)?

Comment: Note that, I don't know your use-case, but by default I wouldn't recommend to use java serialization. You better use a dedicated lib for that.

Comment: @juh The answer to your first question is no not always. The same error occurs when I try the serde on one line, but only in certain circumstances. The code works fine when I run the jar from the `java` cli. I've updated the post to explain how I do the serialization. You might be right, switching to a dedicated lib might be the way to go.